# Хороший глава государства

Tags: прилагательные, лексическая-сочетаемость

Можно ли так сказать? Или к словосочетанию "глава чего-то" не применимо прилагательное никакого рода?

Comment: Или хороший, или никакой?

Comment: Не обязательно "хороший", вот пример с "сильным" меня вполне устраивает.

Comment: Глава чего-то, не обязательно хороший, не обязательно государства? Тогда в чём проблема?

Comment: В том, что основной род слова "глава" — женский, и не было у меня уверенности, что прилагательное мужского рода подходит тут. Понятно, что женский совсем нелепо звучит, конечно, не он.

Answer (score 2):

Можно, так как слово "глава" является существительным общего рода.

Пример: [Источник](https://books.google.ru/books?id=S3yFCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=ru#v=onepage&q&f=false)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, используйте изображения только в крайних случаях.

Comment: Из Нацкорпуса: Но все же это нормальная цифра для **хорошего главы государства** ― пусть получает такие деньги, почему нет? [Морозова Елена. СКОЛЬКО ДОЛЖЕН ПОЛУЧАТЬ ГЛАВА ГОСУДАРСТВА? // Труд-7, 2007.12.19] ---- Он не был бы **хорошим главой государства**, потому что "если ему не с кем воевать, то он придумает фигуры, чтобы с ними бороться, такой уж у него характер". [Бурак Петр соб. корр. “Труда”. КРЕН ВПРАВО // Труд-7, 2005.10.11]

Comment: Спасибо, Елена и М_Г!

Answer (score 0):

Существительное ***глава*** женского рода в значении *руководитель*, *начальник*, *шеф*, *босс*, *патрон*, сочетаясь с другими, обозначающими структуру, объединение или иную общность, образует фразеологизмы: *глава компании*, *глава делегации*, *глава правительства*, *глава семейства*.

Устойчивая конструкция (в вашем случае — термин «глава государства») не определяет род, его определяет лицо, занимающее должность.